# Using List<String> or RDD<String> inside another RDD transformation

Tags: apache-spark, java-8

I wanted to use `List<String> or RDD<String>` inside another RDD transformation method, for example `map()` or `mapToPair()`

Actually i wanted to iterate the list inside RDD transformation method and do something.

If i use the list as static variable its working fine. otherwise its not working, i am getting the list always empty. Also using static variable inside cluster make any issue? Because so far i am trying this in local standalone mode.

How do we use List or another RDD inside RDD transformations? Do i need to use the List as `broadcast` variable?

Comment: You do not want to use another RDD inside a transformation  - you are on the wrong track if you do. If the data is in a List, you do indeed need to  broadcast it. You have to remember that in Spark things are processed in parallel on different machines, so this type of "global" variables have to be broadcasted.

Comment: THanks @GlennieHellesSindholt, I will try to make the list as broadcast variable and check it..

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt Thanks, broadcasting the list worked fine.